# getting some data in a list contains dictionaries for python programming

Tags: python

What is the right way if you want to store certain some info in a list that contains dictionaries into another dictionary? I used a way that keeping extracting data from each smaller part of the list(sorry I do not really know what is the professional way to explain that since I am a newbie).

here is my code :

```
 # TODO: Read database file into a variable
    weu = dict()
    template = []
    LI = []
    with open (sys.argv[1] , "r") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for line in reader :
             LI.append(line)
```

```
# TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as (F):
    reader =csv.reader(F)
    text = next(reader)

# TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
sequence = text
n = len(LI[0])
sub = []
sub = list(LI[0].keys())[1:]
#There is another function that actually gets the data for the value of that dictionary here but the problem is not that so I just put something random for the value of the dinctionary here.
for subsequence in sub :
    weu[subsequence] = 200
element = dict()

# TODO: Check database for matching profile
for i in range (int(len(LI))):
#this line keeps telling me my i is out of range, I do not really know why
    template[i] = list(LI[i].values())[1:] 
    for subsequence in template[i]:
       element[subsequence] = list(template[i])[subsequence]
```

And I did feel my way of doing this is quiet messy. In a Youtube video that explains this program, I saw the author just simply calling that (Which probably did the same thing as my last few lines did in the case my program works right) :

```
for person in LI:
        for subsequence in sub :
            if int(person[subsequence]) == weu[subsequence]:
```

I actually got the idea, but is that the most efficient one in this case? And if I want to do it in my way how to fix that so my last few lines are gonna work.

Comment: [This problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5DCS50+Pset6+DNA) is discussed here.

Comment: Can you please leave the link here?

Comment: Instead of `template[i] = list(LI[i].values())[1:]` , try `template.append(list(LI[i].values())[1:])`